# broadcast receiver of boot completed in android 11

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, settings, android-11, bootcompleted

i faced problem about broadcast receiver of boot completed in android 11 it was working under android 11 but on this version doesn't work, what can i enable in settings or update my source code

public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
private String TAG = "BootCompletedReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        boolean isDialerAppLaunched = false, isDialerAppClosed = false;
        int dialerAppLaunches = 0;

        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           
            Log.d(TAG, "boot completed receiver is working ...");

            Intent intentRegisterDisplay = new Intent(context, RegisterDisplayActivity.class);
            intentRegisterDisplay.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intentRegisterDisplay);
        }
    }, 15000);
}
```

}

i tried to search allow some permissions in settings of android 11

Comment: Can you please add a file manifest to the question?